# Set Blob path dynamically in Azure function Integrate

Tags: azure-function-app

I am developing Azure Function App using portal. I want to set blob storage path on json input file key value name. How I can?

Answer (score 0):

using compiled c# you can specify the path in your function.json file, I'm not 100% sure if it will work in script version (csx):

```
{
    "name": "myBlob",
    "type": "blobTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "path": "testContainerName/{date}-{filetype}.csv",
    "connection": "OrderStorageConnection"
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp-script#configuration